# React-admin nested Array input

Tags: react-admin

From the documentation https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ArrayInput.html, is there a way to do a nested Array input. For this json output?

```
{
  "title": "Simple Form",
  "question_list": [
    {
        "question": "question 1: whats your favourite food",
        "type": "option",
        "optionList": [
            {
                "title": "Macdonalds"
            },
            {
                "title": "KFC"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "question": "question 2: how old are you",
        "type": "option",
        "optionList": [
            {
                "title": "25"
            },
            {
                "title": "35"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```